# Do i use 'else' or 'elif' in this situation? (Exam qn)

Tags: python

Just want to check what is the correct answer for this. This is one of my exam questions and I was told that my program was incorrect ( that i should use "else" instead of "elif". What do you guys think?

Question: Program according to the flowchart.
https://ibb.co/kxe4N5

My answer:

```
price = input("What is the item price?: $")
ship = input("Choose your shipping method(Normal/Express): ")

price = int(price)

if (price < 100):
    if (ship == 'Normal'):
        checkout = 1.1 * price
    elif(ship == 'Express'):
        checkout = 1.2 * price
else:
    if(ship == 'Normal'):
        checkout = price
    elif(ship == 'Express'):
        checkout = 1.04 * price

print("The checkout amount is: $" + str(checkout))
```

Comment: No brackets in if statement and elif statement

Comment: If you did it for an exam, then else would be correct because that is what the flowchart says but if you did it commercially, I'd stick an extra else stating that the user didn't choose Normal or Express.

Comment: @bigbounty It's not a compulsion but it isn't invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: why `else` instead of `elif`. In this case, you do not have other choices so yes an `else` statement would be appropriate. Also, looking at your diagram, the check is on *Normal* method, it is not something like: is it normal or express but it is is it normal.

But this implies that you have correctly checked the inputs.
So your answer is kind of correct because an error will be raised in case of a wrong argument. But without check and an `else` statement, the errors are not detected. With two `else` like that you can fall to the 1.04 checkout.

Plus, I would have some comments:

- You do not test if the inputs are valid. (You can add a `while` loop for that),
- The conversion should not be `int()` but `float()`, otherwise you round down the price,
- You can have a coefficient `dict` instead of writing the same line 4 times,
- Or you can have a coefficient `list`.

Something like this for the checks (I am only giving some directions):

```
while 'shipping method is not Normal nor Express':
    ship = input("Choose your shipping method(Normal/Express): ")
    if ship in ['Normal', 'Express']:
        break
    else:
        print('{} is not an available shipping method'.format(ship))
```

And for the list:

```
coeff = [1.1, 1.2, 1, 1.04]
...
checkout = price * coeff[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just have two possible values, if the first is false than the second has to be true, hence why `else` is slightly better than `elif` here (since with the latter you have to check another condition) even though they produce the same result.

Edit: it would be good practice to validate the input before entering the branches, so you can be sure that your `ship` variable contains one of the two allowed values.

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet should work. Usage of elif is not recommended since it has got only one check. However, we are all students, we will learn the better things eventually. Check the below code, only if and else.

```
item_price = 200
shipping_method = 'express'
checkout_amount = 0 
if item_price < 100:
    checkout_amount = 1.1 * item_price if shipping_method == 'normal' else 1.2 * item_price
else:
    checkout_amount = item_price if shipping_method == 'normal' else 1.04 * item_price
print("checkout_amount = {}".format(checkout_amount))
```

Comment: You have inconsistent usage of comma, do not have correct spacing around multiply signs, indentation is incorrect. Also ternary expressions are not the best here, your lines are too long.

Comment: @Y0da I am not using any comma in code. indentation is a "tab" in my editor, but that should not matter much is what I feel. Also, a constructive way of using a ternary expression in this case, if you could show us that would help in a great way. Perhaps, the proper words used in ternary expression has increased the length of the expression.

Comment: OK for the PEP8 with your update except the too long lines. Again ternary expressions are not recommended: Sparse is better than dense ; Readability counts. (Extract from Zen of python: `import this`)

Comment: In [PEP308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) and [this](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/whatsnew/2.5.html). Creator of the python himself has suggested the ternary operator and defined a syntax. I am trying to avoid extra lines of code by choosing ternary as the flow chart in question is simple and do not involve a lot of decision making logic. But, thank you for the PEP8, very informal and I have got answers to some of my questions in there.

Answer (score 0):

In the shared example, usage of simple 'if' and 'else' is sufficient to achieve the goal. 'if' and 'elif' is best suited for the situation where typical 'case' statement in 'C' or unix is required (which is not available in python)

Please have a look at  implementation given below as well:

```
def displayCheckOutAmmount(item_price, shipping_method):
      def calculateItemPrice(n=1.1, nn=1.2):  return n*item_price if shipping_method=='normal' else item_price*nn               
      return calculateItemPrice( n=1.1, nn=1.2) if item_price < 100 else calculateItemPrice( n=1, nn=1.04)

    In [52]: displayCheckOutAmmount(80, "normal")
    Out[52]: 88.0

    In [53]: displayCheckOutAmmount(80, "normal1")
    Out[53]: 96.0
```